# Check the username in the database, avoid duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I want to do a query to my database if there are existing users of the same name. then I want to send a "return false". but I get only one felmeddalnde right now.

> Warning: mysql_num_rows () Expects Parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

```
function DoInsertNewUser($name, $password) {
    var_dump($name);
    var_dump("inne i databasen");
    //tar kontakt med databasen
    $DBConnection = new DBConnection();
    $DBConnection -> Connect();

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT m_username FROM user WHERE m_username ='$name'");
    $number_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    var_dump($number_of_rows);

    if ($number_of_rows  > 1) {
        var_dump('Användarnamnet finns redan');
    }
    else 
    {
        //ställer en sql-fråga.
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `user`(`m_username`,`m_password`) VALUES (?,?)";

        $stmt = $DBConnection -> prepare($sql);
        $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $name, $password);
        if ($stmt === FALSE) {

            return false;
        }

        $stmt -> execute();
        // ger resultet.
        while ($stmt -> fetch()) {
            $stmt -> close();
            return true;
        }
        $stmt -> close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your query most likely failed. Check your connection.

Comment: if ($number_of_rows  > 1) {
        var_dump('Användarnamnet finns redan');
    } what you try to check if user exists

Comment: use mysqli, doesn't solve your problem, but mysql functions are being deprecated.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2):

you can just count the number of users that have that username.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
 }

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('db_name', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
   die ('Can\'t use db_name : ' . mysql_error());
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM user WHERE m_username ='".$name."'", $link) or die(mysql_error());

$count = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)['count'];
```

update localhost, mysql_user, mysql_password and db_name as required.

Comment: @Max, if it doesn't fail on `mysql_connect`, there's a problem with your database. Check does it exist (using phpMyAdmin for example). Argument 'db_name' must be **existing database name** in `mysql_select_db` function.

Comment: try again, it should connect, select database, run query, and extract result, if any fail it should print out the error message.

Comment: but i have connection. here have my connections class

http://pastebin.com/QK0nG7PC
and

http://pastebin.com/s7gxcRPS

and you se on the top post at i connection to that classes

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT m_username FROM user WHERE m_username ='$name'");
```

With

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT m_username FROM user WHERE m_username ='$name'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: So you have error in selecting database. Check the mysql_select_db

Comment: I mean here you used DBConnection class, so you have to check in that class where you select the database by using mysql_select_db function and also in mysql_connect function that all credentials are proper!

Comment: If I remove the select code so they work? I can log in and everything else

Comment: Yes. You can login if you remove select query. But you can not check the user already exists or not . And other thing you are also inserting user into db so you must resolve this connection error else you can not login!

Comment: Please check the database name with you entered in mysql_select_db function. They are same or not?

Comment: Are you trying this one in localhost or in live server?